# Using Field Calculator with .replace?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, python-parser

I'm using the Field Calculator .replace function to replace WEST, EAST, NORTH, SOUTH to W, E, N and S and I'm using 4 scripts `!PREDIR!.replace("WEST*","W")` and so forth.

I would like to use one string to do this, how can I do this?

Comment: Should "WESTON" be replaced with "W"?  It is unclear what values are to be expected in that field. In any event I think this question is much more Python than ArcPy and so should be researched at [so].

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

Predir field has already North, South, East, West

```
 !Predir![0:1]
```

Comment: good idea to shorten the code

Answer (score 1):

Python allows you to string together functions. In your case, you can string together multiple `.replace()` functions into a single line of code in the field calculator.

```
!PREDIR!.replace('NORTH', 'N').replace('SOUTH', 'S').replace('EAST', 'E').replace('WEST', 'W').replace('west', 'W)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary:

```
ReplaceDict = { "WEST": "W",
                "EAST": "E",
                "NORTH": "N",
                "SOUTH": "S"}

for r in ReplaceDict:
    if !PREDIR! in r:
        !PREDIR!.replace(r,ReplaceDict[r])
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to "one string" would be to use a regex:

```
import re
predir = re.sub(r'([NSEW])[OAE][UR]?[ST][TH]\*', r'\1', !PREDIR!)
```

The question then becomes if it's better to have four readable lines, or one unreadable one that may have some gotchas (the above will shorten WORST* to W too!).